# Database_Exception [ 1146 ]: Table 'database.roles' doesn't exist [ SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM `roles` ]

Tags: php, mysql, kohana, kohana-orm

I am currently setting up a new project and creating my login system. For some reason it seems to be searching for a roles table? This is my structure so far:

Controller

```
public function action_index()
{
    //Check login
    if ( Auth::instance()->logged_in() ):
        HTTP::redirect('/', 302);
    endif;

    if ( Request::current()->post() ):
        if( Auth::instance()->login( $_POST['username'], $_POST['password'] ) ):
            echo Debug::vars($_POST); exit;
        endif;
    endif;

    $view = View::factory('index/home');

    $index_page = $view->render();  
    $this->response->body($index_page);         
}
```

Model

```
class Model_User extends Model_Auth_User {

protected $_table_name = "users";
protected $_primary_val = "user_id";

protected $_table_columns = array(
'user_id'        => array('type' => 'int'),
'team_id'        => array('type' => 'int'),
'username'       => array('type' => 'string'),
'password'       => array('type' => 'string'),
);
```

And the error I am getting is

```
Database_Exception [ 1146 ]: Table 'database.roles' doesn't exist [ SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM `roles` ]
```

Can anyone explain why it is looking for a table called roles? The table in the database is called users.

Comment: what a lower error. Any auth module must depend on some database storage, rdb as mysql or nosql as redis. You'd better to read the module api and description.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see in the [API browser](http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide-api/Model_Auth_User#property%3a_has_many), `Model_Auth_User` has the following `has_many` relationship:

```
"roles" => array(2) (
   "model" => string(4) "Role"
   "through" => string(11) "roles_users"
)
```

This is where the error originates from (as you extend said class).

In ORM's module folder you find the SQL schema used for default authentication:

*modules/ORM/auth-schema-mysql.sql*

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `roles` (
  `id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `description` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `uniq_name` (`name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `roles` (`id`, `name`, `description`) VALUES(1, 'login', 'Login privileges, granted after account confirmation');
INSERT INTO `roles` (`id`, `name`, `description`) VALUES(2, 'admin', 'Administrative user, has access to everything.');

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `roles_users` (
  `user_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `role_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`user_id`,`role_id`),
  KEY `fk_role_id` (`role_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `email` varchar(254) NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `password` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `logins` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `last_login` int(10) UNSIGNED,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `uniq_username` (`username`),
  UNIQUE KEY `uniq_email` (`email`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user_tokens` (
  `id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `user_agent` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `token` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `created` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `expires` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `uniq_token` (`token`),
  KEY `fk_user_id` (`user_id`),
  KEY `expires` (`expires`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

ALTER TABLE `roles_users`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `roles_users_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `roles_users_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`role_id`) REFERENCES `roles` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE;

ALTER TABLE `user_tokens`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `user_tokens_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

Comment: I have now deleted anything relating to roles from this files but still getting the same error?

Comment: Why? Kohana's defaults are quite well thought of

Comment: So the only way to stop this error is to create the tables it needs?

Comment: Of course not. You can either change the `extend` if your class or completely override (I don't mean to be harsh: but what you failed) the parts concerning roles

Comment: Tbh: I don't know if there are other parts within `Auth` that require roles, but I don't see why you shouldn't implement them right away